# Program only reads first row of csv file

Tags: python

Ok basically I have 2 lines of data

```
name    tribe   id  Air Water   Earth   Fire
Pema    Xero    X14C    24  54  34  43
Otaku   Taru    T111F   54  78  65  78
```

Currently, my code checks the column 'id' for errors according to certain conditions, but my code only reads the first row(Pema's row) and stops. I have no idea what is causing this, any help to fix this issue will be appreciated.

```
import csv
filePath ="data3.csv"


length="Length of Avatar ID is not 5 "
name_tribe= "Invalid first letter"
score_grade="Invalid last letter"
mid_integers="Invalid integers"

def isValidAvatarIDFormat():
    with open(filePath) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        remarks=[] 
        for row in reader:

            if(len(row['id'])!=5):
                remarks.append(length)


            if(row['tribe'][0] != row['id'][0]):
                remarks.append (name_tribe)


            avg_score= 0
            user,tribe,id, *scores= row.values()
            if all(score.isdigit() for score in scores):
                average= sum([int(score) for score in scores])/4
                if (average >=80):
                    avg_score="A"
                elif (average >=70 and average <80):
                    avg_score="B"
                elif (average >=60 and average <70):
                    avg_score="C"
                elif (average >=50 and average <60):
                   avg_score="D"                    
                elif (average >=40 and average <50):
                   avg_score="E"
                else:
                    avg_score="F"
            if(avg_score != row['id'][-1]):
                    remarks.append (score_grade)


            if (row['id'][1].isdigit() and row['id'][2].isdigit() and row['id'][3].isdigit()):
                    continue
            else:
                remarks.append (mid_integers)

            if (len(remarks) == 1):
                print (remarks)
            elif (len(remarks) >1):
                for i in range(0, len(remarks)):
                    print(remarks[i])

            del remarks 
            remarks =[]           


print("{0:<10}{1:^18}{2:^15}".format("Avatar Name  |","Avatar ID |","Comments"))        
isValidAvatarIDFormat()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following condition:

```
if (row['id'][1].isdigit() and row['id'][2].isdigit() and row['id'][3].isdigit()):
    continue
```

within your crucial `for` loop makes it skip a row which `id` column's value has digits in selected positions (as it happened with value `T111F`)

`T111F` - symbols in positions 1,2 and 3 - are digits, which makes the loop skip the iteration with `continue` operator.

Your case is not related to a row position but to a particular symbols in selected positions of `id` column.

Comment: thanks, tested it out and it was indeed the line causing issues, have fixed and solved my code as well, cheers

Answer (score 0):

One of your conditionals is removing one line, but all rows are getting read:

```
mortiz@florida:~/Documents/projects/python/testo$ python3 test.py 
Avatar Name  |   Avatar ID |       Comments    
OrderedDict([('name', 'Pema'), ('tribe', 'Xero'), ('id', 'X14C'), ('Air', '24'), ('Water', '54'), ('Earth', '34'), ('Fire', '43')])
Length of Avatar ID is not 5 
Invalid last letter
Invalid integers
OrderedDict([('name', 'Otaku'), ('tribe', 'Taru'), ('id', 'T111F'), ('Air', '54'), ('Water', '78'), ('Earth', '65'), ('Fire', '78')])
```

Because it's a CSV I've formatted it like this:

```
name,tribe,id,Air,Water,Earth,Fire
Pema,Xero,X14C,24,54,34,43
Otaku,Taru,T111F,54,78,65,78
```

name,tribe,id,
Pema,Xero,X14[C] <-- this is expecting an integer.

Comment: uh, so how do i get the error messages to show up after reading the 2nd row of the csv? I really have no idea how to go about doing that..

Comment: You should add an example of the desired output because I don't understand what you want to achieve.